# I want to insert float, but it has an error - Float(s) lost

Tags: floats, errors

Here is the example that not insert float.

[image]

Here's my MWE. If I don't use the figure command, it won't report an error. Please use XeLaTeX to build, because there are some Chinese words.

```latex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]
    { \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray!20] \textbf{#1 #2} \\}
    {  \end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}

\begin{problem}{6}
    晶闸管串联的单相半控桥（桥中$\mathrm{VT}_1$、$\mathrm{VT}_2$为晶闸管）电路如图所示，$U_2=100\mathrm{V}$，电阻电感负载，$R=2\Omega$，$L$值很大，当$\alpha=60^{\circ}$时求流过器件电流的有效值，并画出$u_{\mathrm{d}}$、$i_{\mathrm{d}}$、$i_{\mathrm{VT}}$、$i_{\mathrm{VD}}$的波形。
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{circuitikz}
                \draw (0,0)
                to[V,v=$U_q$] (0,2) 
                to[short] (2,2)
                to[R=$R_1$] (2,0) 
                to[short] (0,0);
            \end{circuitikz}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` you do not want a float, you just want to include the image

Comment: I originally intended to insert a picture, but it has this error.

Comment: no you can use `\includegraphics` to include the picture, you can not use `figure` inside a box, remove the two lines as suggested in the first comment then the picture will be included without error

Comment: It works, thank you very much.